# Moto M unable to boot up

Tags: boot-loop

My Moto M, running Nougat, is not booting up suddenly. It worked fine but after a restart it stopped booting up. It just shows the Motorola Logo and then a blank screen.

I tried Volume Down + Power button Combination and booting it in recovery mode but again the same Motorola Logo and Blank screen.

Never rooted/tweaked in any way.

I have a lot of data in it. Plzzzzz Help.

Answer (score 0):

1. With the phone powered off, press and hold the Volume Up button and the Volume Down buttons.
2. Continue to press both volume buttons, and press and hold the Power button until the phone vibrates.
3. Release the Power button, continue to hold the Volume keys. You should see  a "No command" prompt. (You can release the Volume keys now.)
4. Press and hold the Power button, tap Volume Up to enter Recovery menu.